# How to replace WITH clause in SQL 4.9.5. I am using this in version 8 but my server doesnt supports that

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is my SQL query. I am not able to run it on db version below version 8. It is perfectly running on version 8. But my live server is behind version 8. Help me in this please.

```
WITH ages AS
(
SELECT
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as Date), Cast(dob as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
FROM artisan_bio
)
SELECT
    count(case when age between 0 and 24 then 1 end) as age_00_24_cnt,
    count(case when age between 25 and 34 then 1 end) as age_25_34_cnt,
    count(case when age between 35 and 44 then 1 end) as age_35_44_cnt,
    count(case when age between 45 and 54 then 1 end) as age_45_54_cnt,
    count(case when age >= 55 then 1 end) as age_55_xx_cnt
FROM ages
```

Comment: WITH ages AS
(
SELECT
    ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as Date), Cast(dob as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
FROM artisan_bio
)
SELECT
    count(case when age between 0 and 24 then 1 end) as age_00_24_cnt,
    count(case when age between 25 and 34 then 1 end) as age_25_34_cnt,
    count(case when age between 35 and 44 then 1 end) as age_35_44_cnt,
    count(case when age between 45 and 54 then 1 end) as age_45_54_cnt,
    count(case when age >= 55 then 1 end) as age_55_xx_cnt
FROM ages

Comment: Looking at the [5.7 keywords list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-W), `WITH` is listed for 5.7.

Comment: Can you correct it I tried to replace WITH and tried to join both queries using UNION. But it didnt worked out

Comment: Is there an error? ... if so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Oh, the version changed after edit.

Comment: Yea sorry I miss typed my live server db version is 4.9.5. My mistake.

Comment: No worries, need to know the real situation.

Comment: The exact error is
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ages AS

Comment: The WITH clause is causing the trouble.

Comment: I believe it, would not be in a version that old.

Comment: So sir what's the solution the hosting is not cooperating to update the DB version I have to certainly make changes in my query so it could be run on that version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT
    count(case when age between 0 and 24 then 1 end) as age_00_24_cnt,
    count(case when age between 25 and 34 then 1 end) as age_25_34_cnt,
    count(case when age between 35 and 44 then 1 end) as age_35_44_cnt,
    count(case when age between 45 and 54 then 1 end) as age_45_54_cnt,
    count(case when age >= 55 then 1 end) as age_55_xx_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT
      ROUND(DATEDIFF(Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as Date), Cast(dob as Date)) / 365, 0) as age
    FROM artisan_bio
) AS ages;
```

The change moves your first query to be a derived table with the second query.

Comment: Thanks man it worked out. I am really thankful to you sir.

Comment: Can you do me a favour can you explain me what you did actually So I could understand it

Comment: I moved your first select (from the WITH) into the from clause of the second query to be a derived table with all the ages as the data. (does that makes sense?) [This information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html) may explain better details about derived tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul sir I really appreciate your effort